# Cross-browser way to trigger a double click full screen event

Tags: javascript, html, video.js, html5-fullscreen

I'm struggling to find a cross-browser way to trigger a double click full screen event on a video. I'm using videoJS as player framework and [fullscreen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API). 
I need a solution compatible with IE11, Google Chrome and Safari 10.

This is the portion of my HTML page where I have defined the video tag:

```
<div id="video-js-player-container" onclick="toggleFullScreen()">
    <video id="video-js" class="video-js vjs-default-skin videoSlideBox" 
                         autoplay="autoplay" preload="auto" 
                         width="100%" height="100%" 
                         data-setup='{}' controls>
        <source src="path/to/my/file" type='video/mp4'>
    </video>
</div>
```

Anf this is the script to go fullscreen:

```
<script>
    function toggleFullScreen() {
        var i = document.getElementById("video-js-player-container");
        if (i.requestFullscreen) {
               i.requestFullscreen();
        }   //fullscreen for safari/chrome/opera
        else if (i.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
               i.webkitRequestFullscreen();
        }   //fullscreen for Firefox    
        else if (i.mozRequestFullScreen) {
               i.mozRequestFullScreen();
        }   //fillscreen for IE11   
        else if (i.msRequestFullscreen) {
               i.msRequestFullscreen();
        }
    }                   
</script>
```

This solution works and the video goes to fullscreen just if I click on the edge of the video as you can see in the following picture:

[image]

For instance, if I click in the middle of the video nothing happens while if I click on the edge, where the red arrow points, the video goes to fullscreen.

To overcome this problem I have tried to put my video inside a button tag:

```
<button id="fullScreenButton" type="button" onclick="toggleFullScreen()">
    <div id="video-js-player-container">
        <video id="video-js" class="video-js vjs-default-skin videoSlideBox" 
                         autoplay="autoplay" preload="auto" 
                         width="100%" height="100%" 
                         data-setup='{}' controls>
            <source src="path/to/my/file" type='video/mp4'>
        </video>
    </div>
</button>
```

This solution, with its issues, works. I'm able to click on my video and it goes to fullscreen, but a strange window appears inside the video area:

[image]

How can I solve ones and for all this problem?